# Javascript not working after for loop is done

Tags: javascript

I can't manage to make the line in the code **with all the asterisks** to work. Can anyone help? The function works fine, it is just the `document.write('This will not print');` that doesn't actually work. What is the problem?

//UPDATE//

First of all, thanks for the quick replies. Now I will post the full code.
As you can see the variable ii is declared at the body.

### **FULL CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function runThis() {
var fruta01 = document.getElementById('fruta').value;
var color01 = document.getElementById('color').value;
var problemo = true;
    for (newCount = 0; newCount<=ii; newCount++){
            if (storeArray[newCount].match(fruta01) && storeArray[newCount].match(color01)){
            document.write(storeArray[newCount]+'<br/>');
            problemo = false;
            };
    };
document.write('This doesnt print')
};

//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

//Matriz total
var storeArray = new Array ()

//Numero de objetos
var ii = 0;

//Color de los objetos
var colorCounter = 0
var color = new Array ()
color[0] = 'verde';
color[1] = 'amarillo';

//tipo de objetos
var objectCounter = 0
var object = new Array ()
object[0] = 'limones';
object[1] = 'platanos';
object[2] = 'manzanas';



for (ii; ii<8; ii++) {
storeArray[ii] = 'Tengo ' + ii + ' ' + object[objectCounter] +' de color ' + color[colorCounter];

        if (objectCounter != 2) {
        ++objectCounter
        }else{
        objectCounter = 0   
        }
        if (colorCounter != 1) {
        ++colorCounter
        }else{
        colorCounter = 0    
        }
} 

//print array so that you may see what you can choose...
for(var i=0;i<storeArray.length;i++){
document.write(storeArray[i]+"<br>");
}

//-->
</script>

<form>
Que fruta buscas? <input type="text" size="10" id='fruta'/><br />
De que color? <input type="text" size="10" id='color'/><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" onclick="runThis()"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am assuming that the code being commented out is not intentional and not part of the problem, right?

Comment: is the variable ii defined anywhere?

Comment: Where did you declare `ii`? Did you read the browser's JavaScript console for runtime errors?

Comment: Do you realize that once the `runThis()` function starts working, the `document.write()` is going to clear your existing document and start a new one?  That's what happens when you use `document.write()` after the current document is fully loaded (and thus the document has been closed).  Perhaps what you want is to append onto the end of the document.  Or, if you're just using this for debugging, use `console.log()` with anything other than IE.

Comment: thansk jfriend, however, I still can't make it work :/

Comment: Edited my answer with a working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

The problem is in your for loop

```
for (newCount = 0; newCount <= ii; newCount++ )
```

Should be

```
for (newCount = 0; newCount < ii; newCount++ )
```

---

You don't have to put a semicolon after function, and 'if' and 'for' loops.

Here is a better version of your code

```
function runThis () {
    var fruta01 = document.getElementById('fruta').value;
    var color01 = document.getElementById('color').value;
    var problemo = true;

    for (newCount = 0; newCount <= ii; newCount++ )
    {
        if (storeArray[newCount].match(fruta01) && storeArray[newCount].match(color01) )
        {
            document.write(storeArray[newCount]+'<br/>');
            problemo = false;
        }
    }

    document.write('This will not print'); //**************************
}
```

Just use `console.log()` or a simple alert if you want to check just that.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because the loop **fails**

You never set `ii` anywhere.

Check your console to make sure there are no javascript errors.